# Rails Installer for Mac and Michael Hartl's ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

Can you leverage the Rails Installer for MAC (From Engine Yard) to bypass Michael Hartl's set-up steps for Ruby on Rails?

It looks like by installing Rails Installer you get:

- Git
- RVM, including Ruby Gems
- Ruby
- Rails

I have already downloaded Sublime Text.  Just wanted to make sure that there are no unintended consequences of downloading Rails Installer and then following Michael Hartl's instructions to learn how to build an app. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, but I wouldn't take that chance.

All-in-one type of installers are convenient, but Rails development environment have complicated dependancies and the installer probably cannot cover all the possibilities.

In the long run, installing these things one by one will be easier for you to debug. And trust me, you will get some random Gem errors due to Ruby version or missing dependancies and using all-in-one installers will make it difficult to find out what dependency you did not install.

Follow the convention and install parts one by one as suggested by Hartl.

Comment: Thanks!  I hope to learn a lot by installing everything one by one.